# Using IW and MM in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, date-formatting

I'm using IW for weekly result and MM for Monthly result. But I always get an error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

My queries are these

(Weekly)

```
SELECT 'Data'
       || ',' || TO_CHAR(d.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
       || ',' || NVL(o.cnt_opened, 0) --as cnt_opened
       || ',' || NVL(c.cnt_closed, 0) --as cnt_closed
FROM owner_dwh.dc_date d
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                TRUNC(t.create_time, 'IW') AS report_date,
                count(*)                   AS cnt_opened
              FROM app_account.otrs_ticket t
              WHERE t.create_time BETWEEN SYSDATE - 30 AND SYSDATE
              GROUP BY TRUNC(t.create_time)
            ) o ON d.dtime_day = o.report_date
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                TRUNC(t.close_time, 'IW') AS report_date,
                count(*)                  AS cnt_closed
              FROM app_account.otrs_ticket t
              WHERE t.close_time BETWEEN SYSDATE - 30 AND SYSDATE
              GROUP BY TRUNC(t.close_time)
            ) c ON d.dtime_day = c.report_date
WHERE d.dtime_day BETWEEN SYSDATE - 30 AND SYSDATE
ORDER BY d.dtime_day;
```

(Monthly)

```
SELECT 'Graph,ColumnChart,Open vs. Close Issues' FROM DUAL;

SELECT 'Data,Date,Opened,Closed' from dual;

SELECT 'Data'
       || ',' || TO_CHAR(d.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
       || ',' || NVL(o.cnt_opened, 0) --as cnt_opened
       || ',' || NVL(c.cnt_closed, 0) --as cnt_closed
FROM owner_dwh.dc_date d
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                TRUNC(t.create_time, 'MM') AS report_date,
                count(*)                   AS cnt_opened
                FROM app_account.otrs_ticket t
               WHERE t.create_time BETWEEN SYSDATE - 365 AND SYSDATE
               GROUP BY TRUNC(t.create_time);
            ) o ON d.DTIME_DAY=o.REPORT_DATE
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT TRUNC(t.CLOSE_TIME, 'MM') AS report_date,
                     count(*)                  AS cnt_closed
                FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET t
               WHERE t.CLOSE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -365 AND SYSDATE
               GROUP BY TRUNC(t.CLOSE_TIME);
          ) c ON D.DTIME_DAY= C.REPORT_DATE
WHERE d.DTIME_DAY BETWEEN SYSDATE -365 AND SYSDATE
ORDER BY D.DTIME_DAY;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to group by the same expression you use in the SELECT clause.

So if you:

```
SELECT TRUNC(t.CREATE_TIME, 'MM') AS report_date,count(*) AS cnt_opened
```

... then you have to ...

```
GROUP BY TRUNC(t.CREATE_TIME,'MM')
```

Comment: Show the exact SQL you're using and the error message please.

Comment: I add your suggestion in my query and when i run it i got this error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"