# Using MM in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I don't know what's wrong with my query. I just put 'MM' in my query to get the monthly result. But when I run it, it gives me a daily result in 365 days, instead of monthly result. Please help me.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 'Data'
       || ',' || TO_CHAR(d.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
       || ',' || NVL(o.cnt_opened, 0) --as cnt_opened
       || ',' || NVL(c.cnt_closed, 0) --as cnt_closed
FROM owner_dwh.dc_date d
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                TRUNC(t.create_time, 'MM') AS report_date,
                count(*)                   AS cnt_opened
              FROM app_account.otrs_ticket t
              WHERE t.create_time BETWEEN SYSDATE - 365 AND SYSDATE
              GROUP BY TRUNC(t.create_time, 'MM')
            ) o ON d.dtime_day = o.report_date
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                TRUNC(t.close_time, 'MM') AS report_date,
                count(*)                  AS cnt_closed
              FROM app_account.otrs_ticket t
              WHERE t.close_time BETWEEN SYSDATE - 365 AND SYSDATE
              GROUP BY TRUNC(t.close_time, 'MM')
            ) c ON d.dtime_day = c.report_date
WHERE d.dtime_day BETWEEN SYSDATE - 365 AND SYSDATE
ORDER BY d.dtime_day;
```

Result:

```
Data,01/25/2013,0,0
Data,01/26/2013,0,0
Data,01/27/2013,0,0
Data,01/28/2013,0,0
Data,01/29/2013,0,0
Data,01/30/2013,0,0
```

Comment: Please update with your Output as well!

Comment: I update now @MaheswaranRavisankar

Comment: how to do that AlexPoole?

Comment: Have you pasted in the wrong query [from your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21327979/266304)? The second one there looks like a closer fit for this since it uses `MM` more and has `365` in the filter. Please post exactly what you are running. Are you getting non-zero values on the first of each month, by any chance? That would be because of the outer join.

Comment: sorry @AlexPoole i didn't see my query, i just edited the right query for MM, but I always get a daily result instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial query against `DC_DATE` is getting every date in the last 365 days. If you ran just that part:

```
SELECT 'Data'
||','||TO_CHAR(D.DTIME_DAY,'MM/dd/yyyy')
FROM OWNER_DWH.DC_DATE d
WHERE d.DTIME_DAY BETWEEN SYSDATE -365 AND SYSDATE
ORDER BY D.DTIME_DAY;
```

... you would expect to get 365 rows returned.

The subqueries you are outer-joining to are only going to return a summary count for the first day of each month. So when you join you will get an actual value (which could be zero) on the first of each month, but always zero on every other date. You could avoid that just by adjusting your `where` clause, e.g.:

```
WHERE d.DTIME_DAY BETWEEN SYSDATE -365 AND SYSDATE
AND d.DTIME_DAY = TRUNC(s.DTIME_DAY, 'MM')
```

The that will only show you the first of each month, and the outer joins will still show dates with zero values if there is no matching data from the subqueries.